# Import not importing all functions?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, webpack

https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader

For some reason when I import webpack_loader.utils like in the README.md of the repo, it only imports get_loader (I want get_static). Anyone know why might be going on here?

I have a view where I am attempting to use get_static.

```
from webpack_loader import utils

def app(request):
    url = utils.get_static('index')['url']
    print (url)
    import types
    from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
    print ('meow')
    print ([o for o in getmembers(utils) if isfunction(o[1])])
```

This throws an error: AttributeError: module 'webpack_loader.utils' has no attribute 'get_static'

If I comment out the url code, it shows that only get_loader is being loaded.

I'm confused as to why this is considering the file here: https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader/blob/master/webpack_loader/utils.py

In shell: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA2qe.jpg

Comment: Show the relevant code where the `import` occurs.

Comment: ```from module import function```

Comment: I have a view where I am attempting to use get_static. See OP for edits.

Comment: Weird... Did you try it in the shell (`./manage.py shell`)?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/E8BFs

Comment: What version of `django-webpack-loader` are you using?

Comment: Hey guys, I've created an issue related to this question in the github repository: https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader/issues/114

Comment: @slackmart - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the issue has no attention, I suggest to use pip and install the package directly from github:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader.git
```

This is another way to install a third part package with pip. The command will download the sources directly from the master branch (so you've got the latest changes).

Then you can use the get_static function, e.g.

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 29 2017, 01:40:30) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from webpack_loader import utils
>>> utils.get_static
<function get_static at 0x7f8d56bc0ea0>
```

**UPDATE**

Version 0.5.0 has been released, and presumably this issue has been fixed.

More info: https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader/issues/114